# Cell value from Sheet 1 identical with cell value from Sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, the thing is: I have an excel with two sheets. In sheet 1 I have, let's say, 4000 senteces (arranged in some defined order).

[image: Example]

In sheet 2 I have those senteces on a single column randomnly arranged

[image: Example].

On the column right to those sentences from sheet 2 I write the equivalent sentences in my native language and I don't know how to make all those senteces from Sheet 2, Column 1 as linked with the
identical cell value from Sheet 1.
I will attach an exemple so I can explain this better.

[image: Example].

Can I do something about it? I don't know very much about VBA or excel commands so any help will be appreciated.

If I didn't explain my issue in a way so you can understand, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Sheet2, you may use HYPERLINK combined with MATCH. As example:

[image]

My formula in Sheet2, cell B1 is:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!C"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!C:C;0))
```

If I click in that cell, it takes me to Sheet1, cell C9, where my target_value has been located.

Source: [How to add a hyperlink to another worksheet](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/#hyperlink-function)

Please, notice that I manually typed the worksheet name, with a # symbol at left `"#Sheet1!C"`

**UPDATE:**
If you have 5 target columns, you can combine IFERROR to search in 1 or another column:

[image]

As you can see, each value searched is on a different column. Now formula is:

```
=HYPERLINK(IFERROR("#Sheet1!C"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!C:C;0);IFERROR("#Sheet1!D"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!D:D;0);IFERROR("#Sheet1!E"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!E:E;0);IFERROR("#Sheet1!F"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!F:F;0);"#Sheet1!G"&MATCH(A1;Sheet1!G:G;0))))))
```

Anyways, I've uploaded a sample to Gdrive in case you want to check the formulas:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JjEGno66vRFI2DfEIRLfG3bgHaQwpS4c/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer!
I can't make it work the way you've showed me. In my situation I don't know in which column my value is (like in your example) so I can't really make a MATCH. Also, I was looking for a solution that does not implies another column, but that isn't really necessary tho. Right now, at this point, I am just looking for a solution that does not requires for me to hyperlink 4000 senteces.

Comment: @ChristianChenis How many columns you got? if you need to search in a few, probably you can combine IFERROR with a second MATCH in a different column and so on. About not using a secondary column, that's not possible unles you manually insert the hyperlink or you code something in VBA.

Comment: I have five columns (and 480 rows if that matters). And yes, a different column is good for me in this situation, but I don't know how can I do that with IFERROR and the second MATCH functions you mentioned.

Comment: @ChristianChenis Please, check updated answer